# Understanding of for loop and function c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

Running on Visual Studio 2015 Community edition

Actually i am revising the concept of c++ in which i came accross an error while calling a function. For example:

```
string GetGuessAndPrintBack() {

    string Guess = "";
    cout << "Enter your Guess Here ";
    getline(cin, Guess);    //taking input from user
    cout << "Your Guess is " << Guess << endl;    //repeating back the user input
    return Guess;
}


int main()
{
    constexpr int NO_OF_TURN = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_TURN; i++) {
        GetGuessAndPrintBack();
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It asks the user to guess according to `NO_OF_TURN`. But when the for-loop is defined in the function/Method `GetGuessAndPrintBack()` such as:

```
string GetGuessAndPrintBack() 
{
    constexpr int NO_OF_TURN = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < NO_OF_TURN; i++) {
        string Guess = "";
        cout << "Enter your Guess Here ";
        getline(cin, Guess);      //taking input from user
        cout << "Your Guess is " << Guess << endl;       //repeating back the user input
        return Guess;
    }
}

int main()
{
    GetGuessAndPrintBack();
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It asks for the guess only one time.

Comment: Please consider formatting the second code sample properly, it's very annoying to read as is.

Comment: `return Guess;` because of that , for block will execute only once

Comment: Not sure why you want or need the loop, since even moving Guess outside the loop will only return the last answer given...the other 4 will not be returned.

Comment: i was just experimenting with the for loop.

Comment: @lifehack Here's some ways you can appreciate the answers you got: [__What should I do if someone answers my question?__](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer I forgot to vote. From now on i will be careful. Thank you for telling me BTW.

Comment: @lifehack You can also accept an answer by selecting the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It asks for the guess only once because you have the `return Guess` statement inside the for loop. At the first iteration of the for-loop, the return statement is executed and the `GetGuessAndPrintBack()` function is terminated.

The `return Guess` statement should be outside the for-loop statement.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have a return inside the loop which terminates the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `return Guess` from inside the loop to the end of the method